# three submit buttons in one form html and mysql queries

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I'm using a form, and I have three submit buttons in it. Edit, Delete and Reset but Delete and Reset buttons doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="login" value="'.htmlspecialchars($object['login']).'" placeholder="Login" /><input type="text" name="password" value="'.htmlspecialchars($object['password']).'" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$object['id'].'" />
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="dell" />
        <input type="submit" value="Reset" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="res" />
</form>;
```

In PHP it looks like

```
if($_POST){
$action=(string)$_POST['action'];
$id=(int)$_POST['id'];
$name=(string)$_POST['name'];

$name=trim($_POST['name']);
$name=htmlspecialchars($name,ENT_QUOTES);

    if($action=='add' && $name){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stages` SET
    `name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'");
    } else if($action=='edit' && $name){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `stages` SET
    `name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'
    WHERE `id`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
    } else if($action=='edit'){
                mysql_query("DELETE FROM `stages` WHERE `id`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `questions` WHERE `stage_id`='".$id."'");
    } else if($action=='dell'){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `stages` WHERE `id`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `questions` WHERE `stage_id`='".$id."'");
    } else if($action=='reset'){
    mysql_query("UPDATE `stages` SET
    `name`=NULL
    WHERE `id`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");

    } 
}
```

Comment: First read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In the form there is no field with the name "name" so it will not get POSTed. Each of the buttons is a submit button so it is a lottery which fields will actually be processed by the php script after form submission. Where does the "name" get it's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more the sort of thing you need to make this work - though it is untested.

```
<?php 
echo '
<form id="actions" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login" value="'.htmlspecialchars( $object['login'] ).'" placeholder="Login" />
    <input type="text" name="password" value="'.htmlspecialchars( $object['password'] ).'" placeholder="Password" />

    <input type="button" value="Edit" data-action="edit" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete" data-action="dell" />
    <input type="button" value="Reset" data-action="res" />

    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="'.$object['id'].'" />
    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var col=document.getElementById("actions").querySelectorAll("input[type=\'button\']");
    if( col ){
        for( var n in col )if( n && col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ) col[n].addEventListener( \'click\', function(e){
            document.getElementById("action").value=this.dataset.action;
            this.parentNode.submit();
        }.bind( col[n] ),false );
    }
</script>';


    if( $_POST ){
        $action=(string)$_POST['action'];
        $id=(int)$_POST['id'];
        $name=(string)$_POST['name'];

        $name=trim($_POST['name']);
        $name=htmlspecialchars($name,ENT_QUOTES);

        if( $action=='add' && $name ){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stages` SET `name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'");
        } else if( $action=='edit' && $name ){
            mysql_query("UPDATE `stages` SET `name`='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."' WHERE `id`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
        } else if( $action=='edit' ){
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `stages` WHERE `id`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `questions` WHERE `stage_id`='".$id."'");
        } else if( $action=='dell' ){
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `stages` WHERE `id`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `questions` WHERE `stage_id`='".$id."'");
        } else if( $action=='reset' ){
            mysql_query("UPDATE `stages` SET `name`=NULL WHERE `id`='".$id."' LIMIT 1");
        } 
    }

?>
```

The buttons will call the javascript function that then submits the form with the appropriate action and other params.

Comment: Unfortunately buttons do not work

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console because I have now tested and it submits the form as expected?

Comment: I would suggest that you create the sql statements as variables for each action and echo them out once the form is submitted so that you can see what the sql looks like. Edit them if they look wrong and once ok actually call the mysql_query function. Also, you can omit the `limit 1` statement from the delete statement

Comment: Edit button is working properly, and remove and reset buttons are not working. Perhaps the problem is mysql request. no errors in the console